# What is a good data type for representing arbitrary binary data?

Tags: mercury

I want to read binary data from disk and store it in a Mercury variable.  According to the string library, strings don't allow embedded null bytes and store content with UTF-8 encoding so I don't think that will work.  The best I've found so far is a line in the bitmap library that says, "Accessing bitmaps as if they are an array of eight bit bytes is especially efficient"

Are bitmaps a good way to store arbitrary binary data?  Is there something better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, bitmaps are the recommended way to read/write/store binary data.